# Decode w/ History on Success?

Tags: scala, argonaut

Given:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

case class Person(name: String)

implicit def decode: DecodeJson[Person] =
  DecodeJson ( c => 
    for {
      name <- (c --\ "name").as[String]
    } yield Person(name)
  )

scala> Parse.decode[Person]("""{"name": "Bob", "foo": "dunno"}""")
res5: Either[Either[String,(String, argonaut.CursorHistory)],Person] = 
  Right(Person(Bob))
```

How can I `decode`, i.e. `JSON => Person`, with the cursor's history? By history, I mean, I'd like to know that `"foo" : "dunno"` was not looked at/traversed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately cursor history is discarded when the `DecodeResult[T]` object is built for success case.

The only solution I can think of (it is just a stub to explain you the concept) is to:

- implement a custom `HistoryDecodeResult`:

```scala
class HistoryDecodeResult[A](
  val h: Option[CursorHistory], 
  result: \/[(String, CursorHistory),A]
) extends DecodeResult[A](result)

object HistoryDecodeResult{
  def apply[A](h: Option[CursorHistory], d: DecodeResult[A]) = new HistoryDecodeResult(h, d.result)
}
```

- implicitly extend `ACursor` adding an helper `asH` method

```scala
implicit class AHCursor(a: ACursor){
  def asH[A](implicit d: DecodeJson[A]): HistoryDecodeResult[A] = {
    HistoryDecodeResult(a.hcursor.map(_.history), a.as[A](d))
  }
}
```

- override `DecodeResult[T]` [composition methods](https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut/blob/master/argonaut/shared/src/main/scala/argonaut/DecodeResult.scala) within `HistoryDecodeResult` in order to accumulate the history:

```scala
override def map[B](f: A => B): HistoryDecodeResult[B] = 
  HistoryDecodeResult(h, super.map(f))

//Accumulate history `h` using `CursorHistory.++` if flat-mapping with another HistoryDecodeResult
override def flatMap[B](f: A => DecodeResult[B]): HistoryDecodeResult[B] = ???

... //Go on with other methods
```

- obtain the `HistoryDecodeResult` from your decoding routine (you have to avoid `Parse.decode`) and ask for history.

Answer (score 0):

According with [argonaut cursor documentation](http://argonaut.io/doc/zipper/), you could use the hcursor instead of a decoder, that way you can keep track of decoding process.